# How to parse and substitute a GPU log in awk?

Tags: regex, awk

I have grep output:

```
Nov 07 16:03:23 SA1789 miner[1397]: GPU4 not responding                   
Nov 07 16:03:23 SA1789 miner[1397]: Thread(s) not responding. Restarting.
Nov 07 16:02:25 SA0888 miner[1505]: GPU12 not responding                            
Nov 07 16:02:25 SA0888 miner[1505]: Thread(s) not responding. Restarting.           
Nov 07 16:04:17 SA0888 miner[1505]: GPU12 not responding                       
Nov 07 16:04:17 SA0888 miner[1505]: Thread(s) not responding. Restarting.
```

want to get this:

```
Nov 07 16:03:23 ==> GPU4
Nov 07 16:02:25 ==> GPU12
Nov 07 16:04:17 ==> GPU12
```

```
awk '/GPU/{s=index($7,":"); $7=substr($7,s+1,length($7)-s-1); print $1" "$2" "$3" => "$7}'
```

i am noob in awk sorry, just need a fast solution from experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple `awk` expression:

```
$ awk '/GPU/{ print $1, $2, $3, "==>", $6 }' file
Nov 07 16:03:23 ==> GPU4
Nov 07 16:02:25 ==> GPU12
Nov 07 16:04:17 ==> GPU12
```